# How to get Text From Checkbox in Android

Tags: android

I am new, I want to make A check Box of Male and female ..And Store the Value in Shared Preference in String ..
Can You Tell Me How To get Text From `CheckBox`?
thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use radio button instead of check box and try below code:-

**java**

```
radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

**xml**

```
  <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

see below link:-

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: Golu I saw This example I want to TAke Text Of Radio Button In String
String Male=.....text of Button